# I am getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery' ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: django, nginx, celery, supervisord

I have been trying for 2 days straight to solve this, but, I haven't had any luck
I am running celery with supervisor it shows running I can see it in systemctl and supervisor web interface via 9001 port everytime I run a celery related task I get this error.

```
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/toch/outdoorsy/core/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .celery_config import app as celery_app
  File "/home/toch/outdoorsy/core/celery_config.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
[2023-05-01 00:18:04,062: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task dashboard.tasks.run_scrape_outdoorsy[63235a91-79f9-4976-a6ee-773fa2582a31] succeeded in 0.8941846380475909s: None
```

What is even weird is that the task used to run previously and what's even weirder is that last line show task was successfull and it's saved in celery-results admin interface for django

Running Django with nginx, gunicorn and celery

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this for someone who might have this error in the future
if you are using pipenv and you are running your celery worker and beat with supervisor, in your celery.conf script the command line should be like this
`command=/<path/to/your/system/pipenv/bin> pipenv run celery -A <app-name> worker -l INFO`

to get the your pipenv path do `which pipenv`.
an explicit code will look like this
`/home/<user>/.local/bin/pipenv/bin pipenv run celery -A <app-name> worker -l INFO`